# How to test whether wc -l is even or odd in shell?

Tags: shell

say I have a file called file1

```
$ a=$(wc -c file1)
$ echo $a
233 file1
```

now how would I do this

```
$ b=$(expr $a % 2)
$ echo $b
1
```

I guess the file1 in wc -c make's this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to remove the filename from `wc` is to use `wc -c <file1`. This avoids the requirement of a second process `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like:

```
if [ $(( $(wc -c < your-filehere ) % 2)) -eq 1 ]
then 
  echo file has odd number of bytes
else 
  echo file has even number of bytes
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go:

```
a=$(cat file1 | wc -c)
```

this doesn't output the file name and your `expr` will work.